# How to convert continuous variable dataset into binary discrete values using Chi-Square testing for decision making

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, binning, decision-theory

I have a dataset that contains continuous values for an attribute ranging from 0 - 100. I want to convert these continuous variables into two discreet values (say Label L1 and Label L2), So that the attribute will have only two values L1 and L2. Is it possible to use Chi-squared testing? If no then please suggest some other algorithm for this.

Comment: Why do you want to do this ?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I want to check the accuracy after creating a decision tree. I have done this on information Gain and GINI index. Now I want to perform it using Chi-square. Is it possible to convert it using this test?

Comment: Can you please add this as an edit to the post?